# When velocity becomes 0 and how to recalculate acceleration for final position can be whole number by rounding off?

Tags: algorithm, math, physics

Position P is start with 7.56m and velocity V is 6(m/s). Acceleration A is -2 (m/s): How to get P when V becomes 0 and how to recalculate acceleration A for final P can be whole number by rounding off?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's nothing to do with programming.

Comment: acc. should be -2 m/s2 (unit)

Comment: thanks, but this problem is regarding view animation when user swiping on iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use equations of motion.

```
v2 = u2 + 2as
```

here,

```
v=0, u=6m/s and a=-2m/s2
```

So,

```
s = 9m
```

So, final position will be `7.56 + 9 = 16.56m`

and since acceleration does not change, final acceleration = initial acceleration = -2m/s2

EDIT:

In that case, again use the same equation. Changed values will be:

```
v=0, u=6, s=9.44
```

So,

```
a = -1.907m/s2
```

Comment: Then, how to get adjusted acceleration when final position changed 17? (if 16.56 is rounded off)

Comment: You mean if distance covered was 9.44 instead of 9 in the same time?

Comment: yes, it should be same time. I missed this condition.

Comment: @isaaclee, if this answers your question, accept the answer. There are many questions on SO that are left with correct but unaccepted answers and users waste time on those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)